# Save inputs from multiple users in www app folder so that it is always updated when a new session starts in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

Multiple users will update a data.frame using multiple inputs in a shiny app. I'd like to be able to save every new submission (or delete actions) in the www directory of my shiny app so that the data.frame is always updated every time a user starts a new session.

What would be the best way to do this? App code provided below

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6")

# Save a response
# This is one of the two functions we will change for every storage type

saveData <- function(data) {
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
  } else {
    responses <<- data
  }
}

# Load all previous responses
# This is one of the two functions we will change for every storage type

loadData <- function() {
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses
  }
}

# Shiny app with 3 fields that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    tags$br(),
    dropdown(

      htmlOutput("q1"),
      htmlOutput("q2"),
      htmlOutput("q3"),
      htmlOutput("q4"),
      htmlOutput("q5"),
      htmlOutput("q6"),
      actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
      actionButton("edit", "Edit"),

      style = "unite", 
      icon = icon("plus"),
      status = "danger", 
      #width = "300px",
      size = "m",
      label = "Add new Record",
      tooltip = TRUE,
      animate = animateOptions(
        enter = animations$fading_entrances$fadeInLeftBig,
        exit = animations$fading_exits$fadeOutRightBig
      )

    ),
    tags$hr(),
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"),
    actionButton("deleteRow", "Delete Row"),
    tags$hr(),
    column(width = 12, DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = '100%')) 

  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$q1 <- renderUI({

      textInput("Q1", "...", "")

    })

    output$q2 <- renderUI({

      textInput("Q2", "...", "")

    })

    output$q3 <- renderUI({

      dateInput("Q3", "...")

    })

    output$q4 <- renderUI({

      textAreaInput("Q4", "...")

    })

    output$q5 <- renderUI({

      textAreaInput("Q5", "...")

    })

    output$q6 <- renderUI({

      dateInput("Q6", "...")

    })



    # Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })

    # When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      saveData(formData())
    })


    # Show the previous responses
    # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
    output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$submit
      loadData()
    }) 



    # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("questionnaire", ".csv", sep = "")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(loadData(), file, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )


  }
)
```

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html is a good start.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to that link. I came across it before but unfortunately I am not sure how to integrate it within my code and adjust the server logic accordingly.